# Note items not deleting when I used the reverse method

Tags: reactjs, mapping, delete-file

I am doing a note app with react. I made the notes to be added in a reverse method with the latest note being the first but ever since then, if I click on delete of the first note it will delete the last note and vice versa

On App.jsx

```
    function deleteNote(id) {
    console.log(deleteNote);
    setNote(prevNotes=>{
      return prevNotes.filter((noteItem, index)=>{
          return index !== id;
        });
    });
   
  };
return(
<section id='note-container'>
        {[...note].reverse().map((noteItem, index) => {
          return(
          <Note key={index} 
          id={index} 
          title={noteItem.title} 
          content={noteItem.content} 
          onDelete={deleteNote} />
        );
        })}
)
      </section>
```

In Note.jsx

```
function Note(props) {
 return (
   <div className="note">
     <h1>{props.title}</h1>
     <p>{props.content}</p>
     <button onClick={()=>{props.toggleEdit(props.id)}}>EDIT</button>
     <button onClick={()=>{props.onDelete(props.id)}}>DELETE</button>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an ID you should use that in filter condition.

```
setNote(prevNotes=>{
  return prevNotes.filter((noteItem)=>{
      return noteItem.id !== id; //changed
    });
});
```

Don't forget to also change the ID in Note.

```
<Note key={index} 
    id={noteItem.id}  //changed
    title={noteItem.title} 
    content={noteItem.content} 
    onDelete={deleteNote} 
/>
```

Comment: @Ehceyn I edited the answer to also change the id in Note.

Answer (score 0):

It because your indexes are reverse also.

For example:

```
notes: [{a: 1}: 0, {b: 2}: 1, {c: 3}: 2, {d: 4}: 3]

notesAfterReverse: [{d: 4}: 0, {c: 3}: 1, {b: 2}: 2, {a: 1}: 3]
```

And then you try to delete the first note but it has an id of the last note.

Comment: Don't use your indexes as ids you can generate ids with some random method or find another unique identifier and then you can use the filter in the same way